# In CSS, is ".class1.class2" legal and common usage?

Tags: css-selectors, css

I am quite used to seeing

```
div.class1
```

and

```
#someId.class1
```

but what about

```
.class1.class2
```

?  And I think it is identical to

```
.class2.class1
```

?  Because there was an element with id `someId` but now we have two elements of this type showing on the page, so I want to add a class and use the class instead of id, therefore the `.class1.class2` instead of `#someId.class1`

Comment: I didn't know you could do this, very helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It will select items with both classes. So not items with either one.

```
<span class="class1 class2"></span>
```

Comment: I'd have thought if it did this it would be wrong. Surely .class1.class2 means children of class1 that are class2? So for example, <div class="class1"><p class="class2">This is styled</p></div> .. applying it as shown in your example above makes no sense to me, create a new style with a single name if you only want it to apply to classes with 2 names... otherwise your CSS gets very confusing.

Comment: If there's a space between them (eg. .class1 .class2) that would be true. And you could use it if you style both seperately, but the css for 1 screws up the css for the other, so on elements that have both you need to override that.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is both legal and common. In the element, you would have something like this:

```
<div class="class1 class2">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's nice for syntactic styling. To give you an example, let's say you have the following html:

```
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box">
</div>
```

You can add a second (and third, forth, etc.) class that modifies "box". For example:

```
<div class="first odd box">
</div>

<div class="second even box">
</div>

<div class="third odd box">
</div>

<div class="fourth even box">
</div>
```

Then, in styling, to style different box groups, you can do the following:

```
.odd.box {
}

.first.box, .fourth.box {
}

.first.box, .even.box {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be interpreted by the browser if you give your element does two class:

```
.class1.class2{width:500px;height:300px;}
<div class="class1 class2">&nbsp;</div>
```

If you do like this, it will not be interpreted, resulting on a div with no styles:

```
.class1.class2{width:500px;height:300px;}
<div class="class2">&nbsp;</div>
```

This will be interpreted (resulting on an element with a dimension of 500px X 300px:

```
.class1 {width:500px;}
.class2 {height:300px;}
<div class="class1 class2">&nbsp;</div>
```

The common use of css, is to tell the browser that a certain element with and ID or CLASS of a certain name will get a set of styles, or tell the browser that a certain ID or CLASS will get a set of Styles, like so:

**Ex 1:**

> .class1 {width:500px;} -> *elements
>   with this class will get 500px of
>   width.*

**Ex 2:**

> div.class1 {width:500px;}
>   *-> only a
>   div element with this class will get
>   500px of width.*

**Ex 3:**

> div.class1, h1.class1 {width:500px;}
>   *-> only a div and a h1 element with this class will get 500px of width.*

You can read valid information about css at:

[W3C CSS SYNTAX PAGE](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_syntax.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to confirm the answer given by Jouke van der Maas,
which is the right answer. I would like to quote the following
excerpt from the CSS 2.1 specification:

> 5.2 Selector syntax
>
> A simple selector is either a type selector or universal selector
>   followed immediately by zero or more attribute selectors, ID
>   selectors, or pseudo-classes, in any order. The simple selector
>   matches if all of its components match. [snip]

Since the .classname selector is equivalent to the [class="classname"] selector,
it is an attribute selector. Note the "in any order" bit. Hence the selector

```
.class1.class2
```

is identical to the selector

```
.class1.class2
```

and matches both elements like

```
<span class="class1 class2">Hello World</span>
```

as well as

```
<span class="class2 class1">Hello World</span>
```

which is the same thing, as well as

```
<span class="class1 class2 class3">Hello World</span>
```

etc...

You can also get even more fancy.